# Files not opening in php

Tags: php

I am getting file path from MySQL which is stored in my db to read .txt file content but cannot figure out what's going wrong.

```
$myfilepath=$record['CodeFilePath']; // here getting file path 
$content=file($myfilepath);          // giving it to function file()

foreach($content as $val){           //reading the content from file .txt
  echo $val;
}
```

The error is

> WARNING: FILE(TUTORIAL1.TXT ): FAILED TO OPEN STREAM: INVALID ARGUMENT IN

Comment: are the files in the same directory as the script that is failing?

Comment: @RamRaider yes. If i hardcode the path then it works. 
like : $content=file("tutorial1.txt");

Comment: Can you try `$content=file(trim($myfilepath));` in case there are spaces around the name.

Comment: Also - if your using a *nix platform - file names are case sensitive, so  TUTORIAL1.TXT is not the same file as tutorial1.txt

Comment: @NigelRen thank you so much. That works.

Comment: Just one more comment - would be good to fail gracefully, you could use `file_exists()` first and show some message rather than failing with an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you don't have spaces around the name using....

```
$content=file(trim($myfilepath));
```

Also if your using a *nix platform, file names are case sensitive, so TUTORIAL1.TXT is not the same file as tutorial1.txt.  Windows is a lot more forgiving.